# Play one track while recording in another track in Audacity

Tags: music, audacity

Can Audacity play one track while recording in another track?
I’d like to avoid the whole synchronize process later.

Or is there any other software for Ubuntu with that option?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This question is unclear (at least to me). What are you attempting to accomplish? Multi-channel recording? Monitoring? Please [edit] your post to [clarify.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Of course it can, that is one of the core functions of a multitrack recorder.

Comment: @ElderGeek **CLOSE VOTERS**  Please note that the question has been edited to clarify the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature is called [*overdub*](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/recording_preferences.html#Options) and is *on* by default. It can be configured:

- in preferences: **[Edit > Preferences > Recording](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/recording_preferences.html)‎ > Play other tracks while recording (overdub)** or
- using the menu **[Transport > Transport Options](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/transport_menu_transport_options.html#overdub_onoff) > Overdub**.

More information can be found in [Tutorial – Recording Multi-track Overdubs](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_multi_track_overdubs.html).

Comment: Usually connected problem is that it is **not giving you a new track?** => you have to also check the *"Always record on a new track"* - which is NOT on by default (it is in the same menu `Edit > Preferences > Recording‎ `)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Audacity, there is a large amount of music-related software available in Ubuntu, and several Linux musician resources.

The list of Digital Audio Workstations (DAW) includes, but is not limited to

- [Tracktion](https://www.tracktion.com/products/t7-daw)
- [Ardour](https://ardour.org/)
- [LMMS](https://lmms.io/)
- [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/)
- [Traverso](https://traverso-daw.en.softonic.com/)

All of these are available in the Ubuntu software repositories.  You may also be interested in [Ubuntu Studio Audio](https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio), a subset of [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/) which is a recognized [official flavor of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours), and includes some of these DAWs and a host of other audio related applications.  Your existing Ubuntu installation can add Ubuntu Studio audio with the command

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-audio
```

I personally use Ardour and find that it exceeds my needs for most purposes.  I also use a combination of `arecord` and [`sox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) for the purpose of recording unattended in up to 18 track.

For further introduction to the world of audio tools on Linux, please see https://linuxmusicians.com/ and https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/start